# recover gnome-terminal tab that got disconnected from ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

Is there any way to recover a gnome-terminal tab that got disconnected from ssh connection? Whenever I get disconnected from the ssh connection in a gnome-terminal tab, that window doesn't respond to keyboard strokes anymore. I don't want to recover the ssh connection, just be able to still use the tab after disconnection.

Comment: How did you open the new tab? If it was a shell tab then you should get back to the shell (if still in ssh, use ~. to close it). What would you like to do with tis tab? Why not just open a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenSSH `ssh` client has an "exit" command <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>, inherited from *rsh*.